# How to prove a function is concave? (Single Variable)

Tags: functions, convex-optimization

It has been a while after completing the calculus of single variable.

Right now I have a function of single variable $f(x)$, and that $f'(x)=-c$ for all $x$. So $f$ is a decreasing function.

Bu, $f''(x)=0$. Can I say that $f$ is a concave function?

Before posting this question, I did some research and consult with https://www.economics.utoronto.ca/osborne/MathTutorial/CV1F.HTM.  Quoting from this website, it says that:

> Proposition
>   A twice-differentiable function  f  of a single variable defined on the interval I is
>   concave if and only if  f ''(x) ≤ 0 for all x in the interior of I
>   convex if and only if  f ''(x) ≥ 0 for all x in the interior of I.

Comment: If you believe that the proposition is true, then you can obviously conclude the result (given that your $f$ is twice differentiable.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function graph is a straight line. If you consider this to be concave, it is a trivial case.

Comment: I mean, if f=-x, do you think this function is concave?

Comment: It is not a matter of what I think. It is a matter of definitions. And your definition says that straight lines are concave. And convex, too.

Answer (score 1):

From earlier on that same page:

> Definition Let $f$ be a function of a single variable defined on an interval. Then $f$ is
>
> - **concave** if every line segment joining two points on its graph is never above the graph
> - **convex** if every line segment joining two points on its graph is never below the graph

We have $f(x) = -cx + k$, for some $c$, $k$. Every line segment joining two points on this graph is on the graph - neither above nor below. So $f$ is both concave and convex.